# Printing position of pattern given

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day,

I was wondering if there is a way to know the position of a pattern by indicating the field separator.

**Expected Input**

Field Separator = **,**

pattern = **word**

```
abc,def,ghi,word,jkl
mno,pqr,word,stu,vwx
```

**Expected Output**

```
word,1,4
word,2,3
```

The previous output follows this structure: `PATTERN,NR,FIELD POSITION`

Thank so much in advance for any clue.

Comment: DO your input lines REALLY start with the numbers 1 and 2? Is there REALLY a first line that contains the text "NR"? Does your desired output REALLY start with a line that says "format..."? If not - clean up your sample input and expected output. What should happen if "word" appears multiple times in a line? If the line contains "words" - is that a match for "word" or not?

Comment: Good day @EdMorton, your suggestion is done

Comment: I updated my comment to include a couple of questions related to multiple occurrences and whether "PATTERN" is a regexp or a string (never use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous) and whether you want a partial match or not.

Comment: About the update, the answer is yes and as I am building the data file, I'm only interested in the last match and I tested again with that description and also works. Thank so much again : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution for one possible interpretation of your requirements:

```
$ awk -v str="word" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==str) print str,NR,i}' file
word,1,4
word,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
perl -F, -lanE 'BEGIN {$str=shift; $,=","} say $str,$.,$_+1 for grep {$F[$_] eq $str} 0..$#F' "word" file
```

Comment: hehe... Thank so much Glenn. I would like to ask, if I am allowed: Would you mind to explain me how this perl command line works? Specially, on how perl allow to handle bash commands. Thank so much in advance.